# Не укажете ли все значения пометы 'versus'?

Tags: лексика, заимствования

Я встречала не только "Спартак" versus "Динамо", но и на некоем бланке внизу: vs.

Вопрос: против кого сражается бланк?

Приведите, пожалуйста, другие примеры употребления слова 'versus', отличные от буквального противостояния.

Comment: Это латинское слово, разве его употребляют в русском языке живьём, даже не пытаясь его транслитерировать?  Как его на машинке печатать, например?

Comment: Бланк был медицинский. Помета VS означала: читай на обороте, переверни страницу.

Comment: Бланк противится оригинальности своего составителя, выражающего мысли предлогами :)

Comment: Если большими буквами внизу, то возможно, что это место подписи или личной печати ветеринара (veterinary surgeon).

Comment: Саш, шутить изволишь? Это на самом деле: ПРОДОЛЖЕНИЕ НА ОБОРОТНОЙ СТОРОНЕ, переверни листок-то,  мол.

Comment: В английском такого значения vs. ничему не придаёт и имеет только смысл сравнения или противопоставления (для страниц там есть P.T.O. - please turn over). Остаётся латынь, в некотором объёме знакомая медикам. Там возможно употребление этого слова для указания направления на существительное, которое стоит перед ним (напр. "другая страница"), но оно "должно быть".

Comment: Именно латынь, именно у медиков, но "другой страницы" нет (у направления, например, или результатов консультации), есть только оборотная сторона (полуночи). Просто это единственно мне известное, потому и задан вопрос, где используется... The Other Side of Midnight )))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно употребляется в смысле "против" (имеется в виду как противостояние, так и противопоставление, сравнение).
[Ответ справочной службы русского языка](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer/?s=293538): 
Сокращение vs (оно означает 'против', от латинского versus) пишется без точки. См.: Баранова Л. А. Словарь аббревиатур иноязычного происхождения. М., 2009.

«[Спартак vs. Динамо](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Versus)» (то есть противостояние спортивных команд «Спартак» и «Динамо»).

"На [versus.com](https://versus.com/ru) вы можете сравнить что угодно, от автомобилей до смартфонов или городов."

Весьма наглядно, что в исследованиях Л.Бызова[7] одним из наиболее явных классифицирующих признаков консерваторов оказалось разделение по предпочтению «мне нравится, когда сохраняется старинный облик наших городов и сел» **vs** «мне больше нравятся новые и современные города и поселки». [Сергей Цирель. Какие силы могут создать гражданское общество в России? (2003) // «Неприкосновенный запас», 2003.03.16] (из Нацкорпуса)

Понятно, что тот, кто написал "vs" внизу страницы, имел в виду "переверните страницу". Думаю, следовало написать "verto".

Wiktionary (Викисловарь) утверждает, что одно из значений латинского слова [versus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/versus) — перевернутый (англ. turned). Происходит от латинского [verto](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/verto#Latin) — переворачивать (англ. turn)